# do passwords used in scp get saved

Tags: ssh, scp

Say I am ssh-ing into server A to copy some files onto server B (I need to ssh because I don't exactly know where the file is located):

`ssh A@ip_A`

`scp some_file B@ip_B:/path/on/B`(input the password for the B server)

Now my question is: Does the password for B get stored/saved somewhere in the filesystem of server A?

Comment: How careful/suspicious/paranoid do you want to analyze this? Maybe `scp` on A is "customized" to log it somewhere, maybe any keyboard input on A gets logged somewhere, maybe there is something else capturing the password.

Comment: let's assume a newly installed system

Comment: Not unless there are any shenanigans going on, because this is a well-known antipattern any decent software will avoid. Depending on how sure you want to be you could easily spend years + millions on answering this, because A) you're effectively asking to prove a negative and B) a sufficiently advanced malicious software change would make it enormously difficult to find proof of malicious behaviour (such as storing one bit here, one bit there of the password).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your password is not stored anywhere on the filesystem of server A, unless there is some *really* malicious logging happening on that server which is capturing everything you type while logged in.